# IO operations - Why not cd?

Tags: linux, io, directory, cd

I have no idea if I'm right or wrong on this, but based on common sense, `command file` would be *slightly* faster than `command dir/file` or `command dir1/.../dirN/file`.

Now, assuming that's true, let's think about scripts and commands that involve working with a lot of files in a variable amount of directories (compiling your gentoo kernel for example). If the script or program was smart enough to `cd` into directories holding a lot of files, would there be any performance gain?

It seems to me that the time saved from no longer following those pointers hundreds or thousands of times could possibly make up for the time taken to cd into and out of the directory.

Now I ask my questions:

- Is there any possibility for performance gain?
- If so, how could it be benchmarked?
- If benchmark-able, how many files would have to be in a directory to break even on the time spent `cd` in and out of it?
- Would this also effect file operations for Java, PHP, Python, etc?

Comment: As for cd'ng into directories to work with files...`make` already does that.  Just saying.  :)

Comment: I didn't know that. Seems like I'm not the only one who's wondered this.

Comment: "`command file` would be slightly faster than `command dir/file`" - [WAT?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there any possibility for performance gain?**

count: 10,000,000 (50,000 files, looped 200 times)

`stat *`: real - 8m 47.112s
`cd ...`: real - 8m 47.475s
`stat dir/dir/dir/*`: real - 9m 33.609s

**If so, how could it be benchmarked?**

I used the following commands for my test:

```
mkdir dir;
mkdir dir/dir;
mkdir dir/dir/dir;
cd dir/dir/dir;
touch $(seq 1 50000);
time for i in $(seq 1 200); do stat * > /dev/null; done;
cd ../../../;
time for i in $(seq 1 200); do stat dir/dir/dir/* > /dev/null; done;
time $(cd dir/dir/dir; for i in $(seq 1 200); do stat * > /dev/null; done; cd ../../../);
```

**If benchmark-able, how many files would have to be in a directory to break even on the time spent cd in and out of it?**

It's impossible to know exactly the number without a dedicated system with no other processes running, but it looks like "break even" numbers seem to be:

1 dir: 2,500
2 dir: 1,250
3 dir: 1,000

**Would this also effect file operations for Java, PHP, Python, etc?**

Using common sense, I'd think paths would add this slight time differen, but the only real solution I can think of would be to put all of the included files in 1 directory, make a separate include file to include all of your includes, and include the "mass includer" in your runtime code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a chdir you do a lookup on the directory and create a dentry. Later calls to dir/file should already have the dentry of the dir. Likewise if you do an access to dir/file1 and dir/file2.... dir/fileN the lookup should happen only once for dir. Hence I doubt that there is a performance gain. 'Make' may do the chdir for other reasons.

Comment: I figured something like this was in place, but is there any way this performance difference could be measured?

Comment: You can have a program that does a lookup. You can try running 'stat' as your command since you don't really want data operations to skew your result. You may want to stat a few million files to normalize the results.

Comment: Also check what Postmark [http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/docs/auto-pilot/Postmark.html] does

Comment: I couldn't find anything telling me how to use postmark, so I just used stat. Anyway, I've added an answer with my test results.